# return IDs that have ALL of a list of correpsonding values

Tags: sql, mysql

I have table with 2 columns ....

```
id    id2
1      1
1      2 
1      3 
2      1
2      2
2      4
3      2
3      3
3      4
```

I want to return the ids which have for example `id2 in (1, 2, 4)` but that has all of the values in the list.

In this above case it would return `id = 2`. Is this possible?

Comment: I do not understand your requirement. Can you rephrase the rule?

Comment: SELECT id FROM table WHERE id2=(1,2,4) something like this ... but this of course doesn't work ... I cant make columns like id2, id3 cause this value is variable sometimes 1, sometimes 3 values ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select id
from MyTable
where id2 in (1, 2, 4)
group by id
having count(distinct id2) = 3 --this must match the number of elements in IN clause
```

**Update:**

If the list of IDs is variable, then you should create an additional table that contains the varying sets of IDs, which you can then `JOIN` against to do your filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Are you alluding to [relational division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29)? e.g. the supplier who supplies all products, the pilot that can fly all the planes in the hanger, etc?

If so, [this article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) has many example implementations in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Do a self-join to test different rows on the same table in one go:

```
SELECT id
FROM t AS t0
JOIN t AS t1 ON t1.id=t0.id
JOIN t AS t2 ON t2.id=t1.id
WHERE t0.id2=1
AND t1.id2=2
AND t2.id2=4
```